# Re-opening a misunderstood question

Tags: support, closed-questions

When I asked question [231990](https://askubuntu.com/questions/231990/), I referred to my 10.04 installation as a "custom distro", when I really meant that it had a custom connection setup for wired ethernet (using cntlm to connect to a proxy).

Unfortunately, people assumed that I was talking about some very different flavor of Ubuntu such as Mint or Backtrack, and closed the question as off-topic. I have since edited the question to make clear that I am in fact using Ubuntu 10.04.

How can I get the question re-opened?

Comment: From reading the question, it sounds like loadable modules for all of your devices is compiled out of your kernel.  This will obviously break all hardware autodetection.  In my experience, new hardware recognition in Ubuntu does not require the redhat-y xfree86config and all the hardware re-scanning.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing Perhaps that comment would be better in the original question, where it would help if the question is reopened, or passerby arrive at it by way of searching?

Comment: Custom kernels is OT imo and constitutes a custom distro.  Custom kernel and proxy setting are definitely two completely different things.

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing Can you point out an example question where custom kernel implied OT? Ir shall I start a meta post?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Another meta on "Are custom kernels considered custom distros"  might be good.  If someone wants to field it, sure, but they need to field the question not me.

Comment: related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/232136/why-doesnt-hardware-auto-detection-work

Comment: @AbrahamVanHelpsing See http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/5576/do-custom-kernels-constitute-off-topicness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its re-open, not even going to touch much on the "custom kernels" of topic issue, but simply say I see no reason why they should considered OT.